# Warning while using ListItem, FlatList inside ScrollView

Tags: scrollview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I get this warning when I tried using Flatlist inside View but same error occurs:

`VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

The component I am using FlatList inside is:

```
class About extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            leaders: LEADERS
        };
    }

    render(){
        const renderLeaders = ({item,index}) => {
            return(
                <ListItem 
                    key = {index}
                    title = {item.name}
                    subtitle = {item.description}
                    hideChevron = {true}
                    leftAvatar = {{ source: require('./images/alberto.png') }}
                />
            );
        };

        return(
            <ScrollView>
                <History />
                <Card title = "Corporate Leadership">
                    <FlatList 
                        data = {this.state.leaders}
                        renderItem = {renderLeaders}
                        keyExtractor = {item => item.id.toString()}
                    />
                </Card>          
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

And can I use `leader` in place of `item` here? I tried using it but there was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to hack this would be to use react-native-gesture-handler flatlist
it will sort of take over your parenting ScrollView if you absolutely need to have nested scrollers, at least that worked for me when i had this same problem.

As per second part, without delving too deep of what is what, try reading this [https://www.barrymichaeldoyle.com/destructuring/#:~:text=Renaming%20Variables%20while%20Destructuring&text=In%20order%20to%20rename%20a,rename%20the%20destructured%20variable%20to](https://www.barrymichaeldoyle.com/destructuring/#:%7E:text=Renaming%20Variables%20while%20Destructuring&text=In%20order%20to%20rename%20a,rename%20the%20destructured%20variable%20to) or google any other theory on 'destructuring renaming'
if you absolutely need to rename 'item'.